# Western Digital Re | Hot-Swap?

Tags: networking, raid, hard-drive, sata, hotswap

As the title suggests; my question is:

- Are the Western Digital Re Gold SATA drives for the RAID-systems hot-swap-able?

I cannot find this answer anywhere, sorry if it is a stupid question; but sometimes it's better to ask in order to learn.

Also; this is the drive I am looking at: 
[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6AH20Y2948&cm_re=WD_Re_1TB-*-22-236-525-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6AH20Y2948&cm_re=WD_Re_1TB-_-22-236-525-_-Product)

Regards,

Mitch

Comment: AFAIK it is controller and drive tray (or caddy) combo that supports hot swapping (replacing the drive without powering down and opening the chassis, pulling cables etc.), not so much the drive itself, AFAIK all SATA and SAS drives support that in principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the fountain of all wisdom, wikipedia, native hot swapping is part of the [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Hotplug) specs, so any SATA (and SAS) drive will support that:

> ... However, this feature requires proper support at the host, device (drive), and operating-system levels. In general, all SATA devices (drives) support hot swapping ...